# How to pause listing long text file with cat in command prompt after 10lines then press any key

Tags: command-line, cat

How to pause listing long text file with cat in command prompt after 10lines then press any key.
for example:

```
cat myfiles.txt

bla
bla
bla
bla
bla
bla
.
.
.
bla
press enter to continue
```

Answer (score 34):

You can use [`less`](http://ss64.com/bash/less.html) or [`more`](http://ss64.com/bash/more.html). Both will work.

The `less` command is more commonly used and provides more functionality than `more`.

Using both `less` or `more`, you can traverse a file page by page using the space bar, and line by line using the enter key.

There's no need to `cat` and pipe the file, either. You can just run the command on the file.

E.g. `less myfile.txt`

Comment: Does anyone know why these dont work in initrd or when using init=/bin/bash? Less is not found by Ubuntu's initrd, but more and scrolling dont work making seeing anything longer than a page seem impossible?

Answer (score 16):

`more` and `less` are pagers which deal with paging through text on the console. `less` is more functional, but `more` is closer to what you want. If you specify the `-d` option `more` will show how to move to the next page, and you can use `-num` to specify the number of lines to show at a time (instead of auto detecting the screen size).

```
% more -d -5 myfiles.txt
bla
bla
bla
bla
bla
--More--(4%)[Press space to continue, 'q' to quit.]
```

Answer (score 7):

You should try `cat myfiles.txt | more`

Comment: `less` is more common these days

Comment: You could also try `most` instead.

Comment: or just `more myfiles.txt` without the UUOC.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scroll-lock, although it might not be very useful if data rate is high. <kbd>Ctrl-s</kbd> to block and <kbd>Ctrl-q</kbd> to unblock.

Answer (score 0):

***Alternative***, to scroll back the buffer, while inside a **tmux** session:

Type `CTRL` + `b` + `PgUp/PgDown`

[How to increase scrollback buffer size in tmux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760281/how-to-increase-scrollback-buffer-size-in-tmux)

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative to using `less` or `more` in case those commands are not available. (like my setup)
This does not achieve pause and continue but you can read section by section.

One can use `head` and/or `tail`

```
head -n 10 myfiles.txt
```

The above command will print the first 10 lines of the file

Similarly,

```
tail -n 10 myfiles.txt
```

The above command will print the last 10 lines of the file.

You can combine both commands to read the file section by section
E.g.

```
head -n 10 myfiles.txt // Prints first 10 lines
head -n 20 myfiles.txt | tail -n 10 // Prints lines 10-20 
head -n 30 myfiles.txt | tail -n 10 // prints lines 20 to 30
```

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question as the issue is to _pause_ the output every 10 lines.  Also note that combining `head` and `tail` to read the same file multiple times for the purpose of reading every section of 10 lines would be incredibly cumbersome as you would have to update the arguments to both utilities every time.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).